# Questions involving more than one "sub-question" are regularly closed. But why? This doesn't make any sense

Tags: discussion

## TL;DR

- Questions are regularly closed if they contain more than one "question" regardless of how "closely related those sub-questions are".
- This is dumb: It doesn't make any logical sense, does nothing to aid learning (what the fundamental purpose of the site is), and just causes frustration for users, particularly new ones (of which I am not by the way)
- Finally, it leads to good or even just "ok but still reasonable" questions being closed before any discussion/learning can happen

## Sitrep

I have been meaning to raise this on the meta for some time now but never got around to it.

However having just had a question on the main site closed this evening, this seemed like a good opportunity to raise the point.

Here's a link so you can see the question yourself. [link to closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68746508/what-are-the-best-practices-when-implementing-c-error-handling)

I don't neccessarily want to start a campaign to get the question re-opened. I just wanted to make the point that similar questions are often closed, and it makes no sense.

Here's why:

This question was closed for the following reason:

## Reason 1: Too broad

- Too broad, or contains several sub questions.
- On the one hand, yes it would be possible to split this question into several smaller questions
- However considering the overall topic is tightly integrated into the subject of "error handling" or "exceptions" there aren't really any obvious ways where the question could be divided into two or more questions
- My point being, everything which has been asked is tightly centered around one subject area. It's not as if there are 2 independent C++ questions here

## Reason 2: Maybe would cause opinions to be shared

The question was also closed for being possibly opinion based

- There might be several possible solutions to some of the questions asked, for example, there may be several possible "best practices" for defining how to manage exceptions, but to be honest I doubt it - it's not broad in the sense that there are dozens of possible ways to solve a particular problem, there might just be slight variations in the way that individuals or organizations agree to write code in order to handle exceptions... and even then I am skeptical
- Further to this, it is rarely the case that a question has an absolute and concrete answer which cannot be disputed.

Here's an example of such a question:

- What data type is guaranteed to be 32 bits wide and hold unsigned integers?

Answer:

- uint32_t from the C++ standard width integers library

I'm sure you will agree that if only such questions were alowed on stackoverflow then most questions would be closed as soon as they were asked.

Again this makes no sense. The point of this site is supposed to be for learning. If the majority of questions become "forbidden" then what is the point. At the moment stack overflow is being managed as if it were something like a stone tablet with the 10 commandments written on it - by which I mean no new commandments can be added and the attitude is one of "preserving the current state" (almost as if this is a wiki or the documentation man pages for some old library) rather than allowing new content to be added.

## Reason 3: More than one answer may be posted

Final reason question may have been closed:

- Some people may choose to post an answer which addresses only part of the question.

My response to this is:

- So what? Does it matter that much. The majority of interesting questions here have more than one posted answer. Some answers add something to the overall question and answer which the "approved or accepted answer" doesn't have. Why is that a problem?

While I agree that it makes sense to insist users split questions where it is clearly obvious that there are two seperate questions in one post, in a lot of cases, other users simply see a detailed question containing several sentances, each of which itself is a "question" and hit the close vote button without bothering to think about whether the question should actually be closed or not.

## Summary

Personally I don't really care about this particular interest - I will split the question down into smaller questions and re-post them either way - my point is that I just wanted to raise the point and say "this is dumb, we should probably stop doing this".

## Final, final comment...

Typically the comments/responses indicate that very little effort was made in reading these kind of questions or the question was only skim-read.

One can tell this because the comments are usually very short, hand-wavey responses, with little to no effort. Here's some examples:

- *its a complicated situation, you should read up on it*
- *you misunderstood XYZ*
- *there are probably many ways to do this*
- *XYZ is not correct*

What I mean by this is these are empty responses, indicative of someone who couldn't be bothered to think about the question and would rather it just go away.

Comment: *"regardless of how "closely related those sub-questions are"* isn't accurate. Multiple questions that are effectively just the same question aren't strictly disallowed.

Comment: Your example question seems also to be asking for opinions via the oft used codewords "best practices" so even if you asked a series of simpler individual questions you'd have to avoid that too.

Comment: *"What are the best practices when"* is a huge blaring red flag

Comment: @RobertLongson There are other questions which ask exactly this. So I don't agree. One may ask, what are the best practices when organizing header files, what are the best practices when overloading operators, what are the best practices for writing doxygen comments, etc... It's a valid question to ask, unless the subject matter is one where there is no obvious answer. Such as "what are the best practices when writing a new programming language" which doesn't make sense

Comment: Feel free to point us to them so we can either close them or edit them into something that is on-topic. Generally however pointing us to other bad apples does not excuse yours.

Comment: Your example question is **primarily** opinion-based. I wouldn't only vote to close, but also downvote it.

Comment: Just to clarify my second comment, the red flag note would pre-dispose me to thinking the question will be primiarly opinion based and/or too broad, because often when someone feels they need to specify that what they want is a best practice, it indicates they already know a working solution but want to know what others think. The question is wholly improved by simply never mentioning best practice in the first place, thus forcing you to more adequately describe what you are looking for.

Comment: @oguzismail It clearly isn't **primarily** opinion based. Pick any of the questions raised in there and there is only a yes or no answer. For example *should std::string be used to throw errors*. Either this is good practice, or isn't, or it doesn't matter. It isn't one persons opinion vs anothers, unless it doesn't matter, in which case that is the answer. Not an opinion.

Comment: @KevinB In that case the logical solution would surely be to either read the question fully or ignore it.

Comment: I did, and my initial judgement based on the title was proven correct. ;)

Comment: @RobertLongson I already referenced the example which came to mind. There is a very famous question regarding operator overloading. While it is possible to do anything at all when overloading operators, there is usually only one expected behaviour.

Comment: @KevinB And yet on this question all you did was post short comments indicating that you were not interested in thinking about the question but would rather it just "go away", which really isn't helpful. You could have perhaps tried explaining why you disagree, if you do, but didn't even bother to do so - hence my point - would rather the question "just go away" than actually have to think about it.

Comment: The question should go away, because it is off topic. if it is off topic, there's no reason to look deeper into it, as my efforts would be wasted once the question is deleted.

Comment: @KevinB Now explain why it is off topic

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You disagreeing with my reasoning, isn't me not explaining why it is off topic, ;)

Comment: "Either this is good practice, or isn't, or it doesn't matter. It isn't one persons opinion vs anothers" "Good practice" is an opinion. "Best practice" is an opinion of someone who writes a book or makes a speech about the subject to enough people that listen to them. I say using bit operations to tell if a number is -1 is "bad practice" and unnecessarily obscure. Other people say "it's faster and is obvious to anyone versed in bit operations" and therefore "good practice". Who's right? Are they always right?

Comment: This is a QA network. We expect questions that can have answers. The answers should stand on their own and completely answer the question, not require multiple answers to sufficiently answer the question. (That's not to say multiple answers shouldn't exist, simply, the question should be answerable within a single answer, aka not require a book.) Questions should ask a singular cohesive question so that when a question that is asked is a duplicate, we can efficiently route users to the correct question with the correct answer rather than needing to point to 6 different questions.

Comment: "*does nothing to aid learning (what the fundamental purpose of the site is)*" the fundamental purpose of this website is to be a high quality repository of knowledge. The form of that knowledge has been chosen as Q&A where each question is *specific*. The fundamental purpose *isn't* to be a discussion board or act as research assistance.

Comment: If the questions really are related and you ask the questions in a well-thought-out order, you'll often find that the answers to the earlier questions will imply answers to, if not outright answer, the later questions.

Comment: Your username is quite apt I think. Consultancy is what you seem to expect. Alas, Stack Overflow, the Q&A knowledge base, is not designed to provide it. That might be more the territory of the collectives if that ever goes anywhere productive.

Comment: Literally what is the point of a website that is dedicated to being a huge aggregation of Q&A's which are in theory searchable, but in practice not searchable due to the fact that often one does not know what to search for when asking a question.

What is being described in the comments here is the Quora model, and we all know how pointless that website is.

Comment: Having one question per question is what *makes* Stack Overflow searchable. If you don't know how to search effectively for the question you have, that is a skill you can learn and practice, but also if you don't find your own question by searching then you can ask it (one question at a time), and if the question does already exist, someone else can mark yours as a duplicate of it. Then you've found what you're looking for. It really seems like you think Stack Overflow should be something other than it actually is, but if you had your way then Stack Overflow would be less useful, not more.

Answer (score 17):

Questions on Stack Overflow (and other Stack Exchange sites) are expected to contain one question, because they are meant to be useful to many people who might read the Q&A, not just the individual who asked the question in the first place.

When a question has several sub-questions, even if they are related, this means that people who want to know the answer to *one* of those sub-questions but not others may find the Q&A by searching, but still have to do more work to find the answer to just the part they are interested in. This makes the Q&A less useful to anyone who wants to find an answer to one but not all of the sub-questions.

If your sub-questions are highly related to each other, there is usually a way to phrase them as a single question. For example, a large number of questions on Stack Overflow are posted by people whose code has an error, and they want to know (1) why there is an error and (2) what to do instead. Most of these questions are not explicitly written as two separate sub-questions, and usually people who write answers will answer both anyway.

- Taking the question you linked to as an example, the two sub-questions *"should I just throw a string?"* and *"is it better to implement my own classes?"* could easily be rephrased as a single question, *"is it better to throw a string or an instance of a custom exception class?"*. That question would be on-topic because it is specific, and although it's somewhat opinion-based, answers could easily be supported by good technical reasons rather than personal preference.
- The third sub-question, *"any other notable best practices?"* is not suitable for Stack Overflow, because it is too broad and open-ended even if it was asked separately.

If your multiple sub-questions cannot be rephrased as a single question, then post them as separate questions. If they are related, you can include in each question a link to the other(s), in which case it is also worth explaining in each question why it is a different question to those. This helps answerers understand why an answer to the related question is not sufficient for you.

Comment: Your suggestion is essentially to write all the questions in a single sentence. Presumably one which is an entire paragraph long. This doesn't make much sense, I'm sure you would agree.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant [No, that is not what I suggested](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man). Please read my answer more carefully, and note the paragraph beginning "if your multiple sub-questions cannot be rephrased as a single question".

Comment: I can't be bothered with this anymore